Pick best filled value of multiple occurences of value combination in SQL
I have the following piece of SQL code:
select
   date,
   session_id,
   article_id,
   category
from
   table 

The outcome is now something like this:



date
session_id
article_id
category




01-05
124
xyz
animals


01-05
124
xyz
""


01-05
124
xyz
null


01-05
456
qwert
sports


01-05
456
qwert
""


01-05
456
qwert
sports



I want to have one row per date, session_id and article_id combination. The category should be the one that is best filled. So in this case there should be one row with 'animals' and one row with 'sports'.
If category is only filled with "" or null, then null is fine.

The category should be the one that is best filled. ... can you elaborate on this?  What if a given combination had two non null, non empty different categories?

Then that value should be picked.
---- random string < null / ""  -----
null < null / ""    -----
In theory, there should not be different values for the same date, session_id and article_id combination. Only noise in the shape of nulls and empty strings.

A simple aggregation should work here:
SELECT date, session_id, article_id, MAX(category) category
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY date, session_id, article_id;

The MAX() function will ignore nulls across a group.  And non zero length strings are "greater" than empty string.
